# how to generate a list of endoints using a specific func

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my django app I want to keep track of all endpoints that use a particular function inside them. Let's call the function `caching_func`. I encapsulate my endpoints inside view classes, such as this:

```
class TemplateViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    @action(
        detail=False,
        methods=["GET"],
    )
    def download(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns a Zip file with all generated template files.
        """
        # Create a HttpResponse with the contents to download
        response = zip_file_download()

        # cache response
        caching_func(response)

        return response

    @action(
        detail=False,
        methods=["POST"],
    )
    def upload(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Accepts an uploaded file
        """
        response = do_upload_work()

        return response

    def get_queryset(self):
        return None
```

You can see that `caching_func` is invoked inside the `download` endpoint but not inside the `upload` endpoint. When the server is started, I want to construct a list of the endpoints that use `caching_func`, and I want the output to be the full endpoint name, not just the method name. For instance, the snippet below is in the urls.py file of the app:

```
router.register(
    r"template",
    TemplateViewSet,
    basename="download-template",
)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

So if the final endpoint urls are `/template/download/` and `/template/upload/`, then the list of endpoints that use `caching_func` should be `["/template/download"]`.

Please describe how you think I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build that manually using the framework [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) utility function.

```py
def caching_func_endpoint_tracker():
    endpoints = [
        reverse("download-template-download"),
        reverse("another-basename-action"),
        ...
    ]
```

As far as I can see, doing it automatically would be kind of complex, since theoretically you would use such function inside different actions of different views, thus changing the `basename` and `action`, which is the information that the [`router`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage) uses to build its patterns.

If you are wondering, the pattern is not wrong. The basename you set is `download-template` and the action is `download`, so `reverse("download-template-download")` is correct.